# Array out of bounds Java Code

Tags: java, arrays

Please help me to figure out array index out of bounds error in following simple code. I am running this code in eclipse.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Union_Find {

public static void intialization(int arr[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
     {
         arr[i]=i;
     }
}

public static void print(int arr[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++);
    {
        System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please enter array size");
    int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    int arr[]=new int[n];
    intialization(arr);
    print(arr);
}
}
```

Comment: On which line are you getting this?  What do you see in eclipses debugger when this happen?

Comment: @Aubin: He didn't remove it.

Comment: Now that Rohit has correctly diagnosed the problem its no longer so critical; but in future provide a full stack trace (i.e. the whole exception message) and mark which line it occured on (as stack overflow does not provide line numbers). This will make diagnosing problems much quicker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice the semi-colon after the loop in your print method:

```
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++);
```

now this for loop will run till `i == arr.length - 1`, and do nothing. And as the value is equal to `arr.length`, it ends, and then the next block, which is just a local block unrelated to `for` loop:

```
{
    System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);
}
```

is executed, and throws ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception, as it is really trying to access `arr[arr.length]`.

Coincidentally, you have also declared `int i` outside the loop in that method only, else the compiler would have marked that print statement as error.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was all because of semicolon.

Comment: @user2737926. Please remember that the next time you post any question, also post the stack trace of the exception that you get, or in case of compiler error, the exact error message. It would be much easier to solve the issue then.